# How do I modify my manifest file in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I'm very new to Java and a bit out of my element, but I have a Web Start Application/applet that I'm trying to change the manifest file on. I want to include the line `Trusted-Library: true`

I clicked over to the "Files" tab, double-clicked on "manifest.mf" in the "build" folder, and edited the file to include this. However, as soon as I run a "Clean & Build," the manifest file is apparently overwritten, as the line I added disappears right before my eyes.

How do I include this line? Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using ant with netbeans to build your project, basically you need to modify build process to include manifest attribute you want in generated manifest

[here](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Netbeans/How_to_Add_Version_Information_to_a_Jar_File_with_Netbeans) is detailed tutorial

Comment: I tried following the tutorial, but I don't think it's working. Here's my [build.xml file](http://jsfiddle.net/VHh6j/). It's importing `nbproject/build-impl.xml` and that file (which was auto-generated by NetBeans) also includes some manifest instructions that I think are overriding whatever I try to do. Does that make sense? Thanks for your patience; like I said I am very new at this!

Comment: can you try to debug to see if build project invokes that ant target

Comment: 1) I'm not sure how to do that, and 2) it's a web start application so it's an applet that runs in the browser, meaning that normal debug mode won't work.

Comment: try adding some echo on that target and see if it prints on console when you build it check build log

Comment: I didn't really use your tutorial at all, but I'm still going to give you credit for this question because you helped lead me on the right path. I looked in the `nbproject/build-impl.xml` file and found a tag called `<customize/>` inside of a `<manifest>` tag. I just added various `<attribute>` tags at that point and that seems to have worked.